# How to ignore empty lists in jackson?

Tags: java, json

I have the following entities that i want my web service to pass as jsons

```
@Entity(name = "tests")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "test_name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Question> questions;

}

@Entity(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String question;

    @Column(name = "is_multi_select")
    private boolean isMultiSelect;

    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Answer> answers;

}
```

The problem is i want the question list not to be included in my json, but i just can't make jackson ignore them.

I tried to annotated the question list with `@JsonIgnore`, but no result. How do i do this?

P.S.

Forgot to mention that the serialization is done via jersey, and here's the method that actually returns my test list

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/tests")
public Response getLanguageList() {
    List<Test> tests = TestDao.getTests();
    return Response.status(200).entity(tests).build();
}
```

Comment: Actually `@JsonIgnore` should work. Can you show the code that is serializing the entities to JSON?

Comment: the point is i'm not serializing by hand, the jersey is handling that when building response

Answer (score 6):

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

NON_EMPTY makes include only non null fields and not empty collection type fields.

Comment: Worked for me. Optional code: '@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)', makes same filter but for primitive types not recomended.

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure your mapper to ignore empty arrays:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
```

To ignore a specific property, the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` annotation should do:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Question> questions;
```

**EDIT:** You may need to enable Jackson with this in your `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

or configuring though code:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

Reference: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/json.html

Comment: just edited my question, can you please tell how can i do this for jax-rs?

Comment: @Carmine, updated answer with reference to the Jersey JSON documentation.

Comment: WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS has been deprecated - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135059/232175 for alternatives