# Alternatives to @Deprecated SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS

Tags: java, jackson, deprecated

I'm having difficulties figuring out the correct way to fix the deprecation warnings on `SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS`.

Javadocs state that

> Since 2.8 there are better mechanism for specifying filtering;
>   specifically using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat or
>   configuration overrides.

but I would assume that

```
ObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
```

*is* a configuration override, although the line above triggers a deprecation warning.

What are other alternatives that do not pollute model classes with yet another annotation? I want to configure the behaviour globally.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the class level, you can use the @JsonInclude like:

```
@JsonInclude( JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY )
public class MyClass ...
```

Also, at the mapper level you can do something like:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

Comment: The second one does not work for overriding the annotation on the POJO. The deplrecatred one does.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc is just plain wrong.

1. `"using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat"`: There are plenty of cases where annotations are patently NOT better, most notably when you *can't* annotate the POJOS because you don't own them, or when you need to *override* the annototations to get a different behavior than you usually want.
2. `"configuration overrides"`: That would be great, but to my knowledge there are no other overrides that will take precedence over annotations.

From the user perspective, the only thing bad about the deprecated option is that it is deprecated, and thus might not be supported in the future.  That is of course a real concern - you might one day have to choose between a vital security update and keeping your code working without a rewrite.

Comment: Update: the author recognises the issue, and it seems unlikely that the functionality will be removed before a functional equivalent is in place. 
 Ref: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1547